# Multiple custom validators for one field in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How can I distinct which validator fails when they listen to the same input field ?
Let's say I have simple input field and two custom validator attached to that field: **myValidator1** and **myValidator2**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Character Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" 
    ngModel required myValidator1="name" myValidator2="name"
    #nameCtrl="ngModel">
    <span class="help-lock" *ngIf="nameCtrl.invalid && nameCtrl.touched">Please enter a name!</span>
    <small [hidden]="nameCtrl.valid">
      Some error occur
    </small>
  </div>
```

I implemented those two validators as shown below:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myValidator1]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DuplicateCharValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class Validator1 implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    if (this.swService.someValidation(control.value) !== -1) {
      return { myValidator1 : false };
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(private swService: StarWarsService, @Attribute('myValidator1') public myValidator1 : string) { }
}
```

Second validator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myValidator2]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DuplicateCharValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class SomeOtherValidation implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
    if (this.swService.validateSomethingDifferent(control.value) !== -1) {
      return { myValidator2 : false };
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(private swService: StarWarsService, @Attribute('myValidator2') public myValidator2 : string) { }
}
```

My question if what should I return in order to know if validation1 fails or validation2 fails ? As far as I know these validations set **ng-invalid** to input field but I don't know if it was set because of first or second validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `field.errors.myValidator1` and `field.errors.myValidator2`

but in your directive you have to return `true` as

```
 return { myValidator1 : true };
```

then use:

```
<span *ngIf="nameCtrl.errors.myValidator1">Validator 1 failed</span>
<span *ngIf="nameCtrl.errors.myValidator2">Validator 2 failed</span>
```

**Edit:**

If the compilers complains about `errors.myValidator1` not defined, then you can use square brackets to access that member like: `nameCtrl.errors['myValidator1']`

Comment: well actualy it sounds nice buy I get an error. When I write nameCtrl.errors.myValidator1 compiler unserscore it and give me an error  'myValidator1' is not defined '__type' does not contain such a member.

Comment: Well you can simply use the squared brackets instead of dot notation :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hint from callback I manage to make it work.
As mentioned you need to return key : value from your custom validator e.g.

```
return { myValidator1 : true };
```

Then you can acess it from html like this:

```
<span *ngIf="nameCtrl.errors['myValidator1']">Validator 1 failed</span>
```